# Embedded collection of embedded collection - isValid issue

Tags: symfony

Let's say I've got a `FooType` with `BarType` (collection; cascade validation setted to true) which itself has a `FooBarType` (collection; cascade validation setted to true)

So

```
//FooType
$builder
  [...]
  ->add('bar', 'collection', [
      //...
      'type' => new BarType()
      'error_bubbling' => false,
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'required' => false,
      'by_reference' => false,
      ]
  );
```

---

```
//BarType
$builder
  [...]
  ->add('fooBar', 'collection', [
      //...
      'type' => new FooBarType()
      'error_bubbling' => false,
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'required' => false,
      'by_reference' => false,
      ]
  );
```

Now the problem is, if I add from GUI one element to `fooBar` collection that's invalid due to Valid constraints, the error is attached to WHOLE collection (and not to collection's element field) and the element claim to be valid (saw from profiler). If I add from GUI more than one element to `fooBar` collection is still invalid, invalid status (error) is still attached to collection, first element still claims to be valid but other ones has error attached (that is what I desire).

### Question

Why such behavior? Any ideas?

---

### Additional info

This is the invalid path shown in profiler

> Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.bar[0].foobar[0].fieldName =
> null

that got the actual value, but is "tied" to collection and not to field element.

Symfony version: 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty "easy" but hard to find.

I asked to myself if it was better to delete the question or to answer here directly. As I'm pretty sure that this error could happen also to other people and "investigation" isn't so easy, I've decided to answer indeed.

### Mistake

Mistake was onto collection prototype javascript and its indexes. I'm talking about

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

`addTagForm()` javascript function, that in my case was customized in order to reach what I need. The problem was I made a mistake onto index calculation so every new collection was starting from 1 instead of 0.

Thus, when form validation component tried to attach error to right field, producing this

> Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.bar[0].foobar[0].fieldName =
>   null

no field (at `foobar` level) with `index = 0` was find and error was attached to its parent (the collection).

So when I added more then one element to collection, every error I saw was relative to "other" field (in a n-1 fashion).

### How i spot this error

Using profiler > form , onto left column you can spot all form fields with error attached. Observing indexes you can find what I'm talking about.